# rewrite rule and rewrite cond to rewrite URL in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get apache to rewrite cond/rules to rewrite the location of my bootstrap files which are located in a folder called /assets which is NOT in the root directory.

I have added the rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

to try to catch a url such as:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
```

the full url the browser tries to find is:

```
http://feeder.xxxxx.com/site/page/alert/v1/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

Which incorrectly has the REST/ information included in the url.

I need to divert it to:

```
http://feeder.xxxxx.com/templates/assets/css/app.css
```

I am currently using codeigniter (which I don't think makes any difference to this issue except for the MVC framework)

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use **absolute URL** for you rule to work, see below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/app.css">
```

If you need to redirect /assets to /templates/assets then another rule is needed:

```
RewriteRule ^/?assets/(.+) /templates/assets/$1 [L]
```

The final .htaccess should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Redirect /assets to /templates/assets
RewriteRule ^/?assets/(.+) /templates/assets/$1 [L]
```

On the sidenote, presense of the question mark (`?`) after `index.php` doesn't seem right and looks like your application is misconfigured (maybe `$config['enable_query_strings']` is set to `TRUE`). Please see [CodeIgniter URLs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) for more information.